# Syntax for the OPENROWSET query

Tags: sql, excel, openrowset

What is the correct syntax for the following SQL code in order to get data as at 2013-03-04?

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\SQL Server\DataInput\Info.xlsm;'
, 'SELECT * FROM [Index_Info$]
where [Index_Info_Last Fixed Date] = 2013-03-04 ');
```

In common SQL query the variable date should be inculded between two ' ', but writing '2013-03-04'the query returns:

```
Incorrect syntax near '2013'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape your apostrophes surrounding the date literal, as such:

```
'SELECT * FROM [Index_Info$]
where [Index_Info_Last Fixed Date] = ''2013-03-04'' '
```

Comment: I discovered that reading from an Excel file data containing dates they should be sfecified in the Excel format, therefore 41337 instead of 2013-03-04.

Comment: @LorenzoRigamonti: Good to know. Feel free to answer your own question and mark your own answer as the accepted one. This will be helpful to future visitors